# promise state and difference in execution

Tags: javascript, promise

hi guys here is the code ...
the **console.log(myPromise);** in 1st code always logs that promise's state is pending while the **console.log(myPromise2);** in 2nd code shows weither it's fullfilled or rejected...
would someone explain difference between the two sections and  order of execution in each one (that stuff of asynchronous ...)

---

```js
    // 1st code 
    const myPromise = new Promise((resolveFunction, rejectFunction) => {
       let connect = false;
       if (connect) {
         resolveFunction("Connection Established");
       } else {
         rejectFunction(Error("Connection Failed"));
       }
     }).then(
       (resolveValue) => console.log(`Good ${resolveValue}`),
       (rejectValue) => console.log(`Bad ${rejectValue}`)
     );
    console.log(myPromise);

    // always logs that state is pending 

    // 2nd code

    const myPromise2 = new Promise((resolveFunction, rejectFunction) => {
      let connect = true;
      if (connect) {
        resolveFunction("Connection Established");
      } else {
        rejectFunction(Error("Connection Failed"));
      }
    });

    console.log(myPromise2);

    myPromise2.then(
       (resolveValue) => console.log(`Good ${resolveValue}`),
       (rejectValue) => console.log(`Bad ${rejectValue}`)
     );
// the 2nd one logs weither it's fullfiled or rejected
```

Comment: It's simply that the promise is still pending / already settled *when being logged*, since you're logging different promises. Does it matter? No. In real code, a promise should only be used when it's actually resolved asynchronously, so logging the promise immediately after its construction should *always* show it as pending.

Comment: You may want to learn about [the event loop](https://youtu.be/cCOL7MC4Pl0).

Answer (score 0):

Running `then` creates another promise.

So as in the second example, you run only one promise, the `console.log` displays it as already fulfilled.

In the first one when `console.log` runs the first promise is fulfilled, but the second one is still in the microtask queue.

```js
const a = new Promise(r => r(1))
const b = a.then(r => r + 1)
const c = b.then(r => r + 1)

console.log(a)
console.log(b)
console.log(c)
```

[image: console output]

Also, using `new Promise((resolve, reject) => {})` constructor makes the code inside run immediately, hence it's already fulfilled when you `console.log`

Comment: Well don't expand them and it'll [look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wurzv.png). That's what the OP is asking about.

Comment: Ok, I understand it now. I will explain in a moment

Comment: @KonradLinkowski

Comment: @KonradLinkowski would you explain what does mean / do that " r(1) " in the callback function of 1st promise in const " a " ??? ofc i tried running the code but i want explication of that syntax or somewhere to read about it .....

Comment: It's the same syntax you are using in your question. You named your parameter `resolveFunction` I named it `r` for short. Just passing `1` to `r` to be short.